# Make dummy target that checks the age of an existing file?

Tags: makefile, dependencies, data-manipulation, data-management

I'm using make to control the data flow in a statistical analysis. If have my raw data in a directory `./data/raw_data_files`, and I've got a data manipulation script that creates cleaned data cache at `./cache/clean_data`. The make rule is something like:

```
cache/clean_data:
  scripts/clean_data
```

I do not want to touch the data in `./data/`, either with make, or any of my data munging scripts. Is there any way in make to create a dependency for the cache/clean_data that just checks whether specific files in `./data/` are newer than last time make ran?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `clean_data` is a single file, just let it depend on all data files:

```
cache/clean_data: data/*
    scripts/clean_data
```

If it is a directory containing multiple cleaned files, the easiest way is to write a stamp file and have that depend on your data files:

```
cache/clean_data-stamp: data/*
    scripts/clean_data
    touch cache/clean_data-stamp
```

Note that this regenerates all `clean_data` files if one data file changes. A more elaborate approach is possible if you have a 1-to-1 mapping between data and cleaned files. The GNU Make Manual has a [decent example of this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html#Prerequisite-Types). Here is an adaptation:

```
 DATAFILES:= $(wildcard data/*)
 CACHEFILES:= $(patsubst data/%,cache/clean_data/%,$(DATAFILES))

 cache/clean_data/% : data/%
         scripts/clean_data --input $< --output $@

 all: $(CACHEFILES)
```

Here, we use [wildcard](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html#Wildcard-Function) to get a list of all files under `data`. Then we replace the data path with the cache path using [patsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions). We tell `make` how to generate cache files via a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage), and finally, we define a target `all` which generates all the required cache files.

Of course you can also list your `CACHEFILES` explicitly in the Makefile (`CACHEFILES:= cache/clean_data/a cache/clean_data/b`), but it is typically more convenient to let `make` handle that automatically, if possible.

Notice that this complex example probably only works with GNU Make, not in Windows' nmake. For further info, consult the [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/), it is a great resource for all your Makefile needs.

Comment: Care to elaborate? That sounds useful :)

Comment: Ah, that is cool. I won't be able to use it for this project, cause it's not 1-to-1, but I can see it being useful in the future.