# How to use makefile to trigger data processing when input files changed?

Tags: bash, makefile, data-science

I would like to have data processing performed when launching make and one or more files in the input directory have changed. With my current Makefile processing is not triggered.

Let's say, I'm setting up an exemplary project: two directories, one with data files. Use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p proj/input
mkdir -p proj/output
cd proj/input
echo "a2018" > 2018a.txt
echo "b2018" > 2018b.txt

echo "a2019" > 2019a.txt
echo "b2019" > 2019b.txt
```

My Makefile:

```
#proj/Makefile

RAW := $(shell find input -name "*.txt")
OUT := ./output

.PHONY: all

all: $(OUT)/*.txt
    echo "Running processing of raw files"

$(OUT)/2018merged.txt: $(RAW)
    ./merge.sh 2018

$(OUT)/2019merged.txt: $(RAW)
    ./merge.sh 2019
```

The merge script does basic concatenation of files by year from the filename and saves the result in the file in the output directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
# proj/merge.sh

echo "-- merging files for $1"
cat input/$1*.txt > "./output/$1merged.txt"
```

I believed that providing all files in the input directory as a prerequisite will be sufficient but apparently I'm doing something wrong.
I found few questions around similar poblems and partial solutions might be there:

- [Processing multiple files generated from single input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54956522),
- [Make: How to process many input files in one invocation of a tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594630),
- [Make dummy target that checks the age of an existing file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905687).

Answer (score 0):

Consider this rule:

```
all: $(OUT)/*.txt
        echo "Running processing of raw files"
```

This says, `all` depends on all the files in the `$(OUT)` directory that match the pattern `*.txt`.

Well, of course before you've run your makefile there *are no files*: that's the whole point of your makefile to create them.  So when you first run make that pattern expands to nothing, and thus there are no prerequisites for `all`, and thus nothing is done.

If you want to construct the list of targets to build you have to do it based on the *source* files, which will always exist, or in this case where they don't match up exactly you have to list them explicitly:

```
YEARS = 2018 2019

all: $(patsubst %,$(OUT)/%.txt,$(YEARS))
        echo "Running processing of raw files"
```